# Can I expect more performance with a gpu installed when sw-decoding a video file?

Tags: video, gpu, video-streaming

My gpu is currently Intel HD 630, which comes with a i5 7500. **I've suffered some stuttering when sw-decoding some videos (Apple Prores) in my NAS whose bit-rate is about 150-200Mbps.** However, it seems the connection is not the problem because the statistics on MPC-HC indicates a decent amount of buffer. *FYI, my router supports a total of 867Mbps.*

In this situation, I consider buying a external gpu. **However, I'm a bit skeptical because "sw-decoding" literally doesn't highly involve the gpu's performance.** Would buying a new gpu resolve this stuttering?

Comment: Before buying a dedicated GPU, see whether you can enable hardware decoding for Apple ProRes on your current iGPU. Lastly: Software decoding is *always* going to be done on the CPU, no matter what GPU you have.

Comment: @GiantTree What's interesting about this problem is that, when I copy the file into my ssd and play it, there's no stuttering... Maybe the cpu lose some performance to get the file from NAS...?

Comment: @Il-seobBae that would be somewhat important information to have in your question. The WiFi could well be causing an additional CPU load, have you tried a wired gigabit connection?

Comment: @Mokubai You were right. The wired connection causes no problem... It's a dilemma...!

Comment: Also keep in mind that just because you have a negotiated speed of 867Mbps over WiFi doesn't mean anything like that will reach your device. I usually have about 700Mbps on WiFi but only 50-100Mbps reach my device although the server is connected over a Gigabit connection to the router. You share the speed across *all* connected devices and one additional device can reduce the effective speed quite by a bit.

Comment: @GiantTree Thank you for the advice. However, I already mentioned above there's a decent amount of buffer when playing those files.

Comment: There are probably a couple of problems at play here. Because you are using an on board GPU it will be using an amount of your system memory and therefore memory bandwidth  to do the final display render of the video to the display buffer but I wouldn't expect that to use enough to cause a problem. It is entirely possible that your WiFi drivers are a problem as they are notorious for causing a high DPC latency which can cause poor CPU performance. I'd have a look for updated WiFi drivers in the first instance.

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you for the detailed explanation. Since the driver is up to date, I have nothing better to do...